# Stretch input field height to fill table cell

Tags: html, css, input, height

How do you make an input field stretch to the height of a table's cell using plain css for ie8?

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>line1<br />line2</td>
        <td><input type = "text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`height:100%` on the input does not work and neither does a combination of:

```
    height:inherit;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
```

If the answer is you cannot, then that is fine, i'll put some jquery together to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding:0` to td and `height:100%` to input

```
input { 
    height:100%; 
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
td {        
    border:solid green 1px;
    background:pink;
    padding:0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rs2eT/1/)**

Comment: To clear up some confusion here, this code will work in for example Chrome, but it won't work in for example Firefox.

Comment: What does not work with the example?  I can't seem to get JSFiddle to work when I emulate IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to work with the proposed answer/solution :-(
I added a larger content to another cell, and the input is not scaling to height 100%. Tested in Chrome Version 120.0.6099.225 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

[image]

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>jgfkjff</h1>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type = "text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5yko26gu/

Answer (score -1):

Add `height:100%;` to your input and set height of your td tag in percents